# I have bad video playback on Ubuntu 13.10 with the AMD E2 vision processor

Tags: ati, video

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on an HP 2000 laptop with an AMD E2 vision processor and 4gb ram. Now the makers of AMD claim it's supposed to grant great video playback at HD but at 720p I get choppy video playback running only firefox or for that matter chromium. Any advice.